# Bootstrap slider, arrange value to the right

Tags: bootstrap-4

I would like to display the value of the slider to the right of the slider rather than underneath. If I move the div to a column, the slider does not work.
I'm using bootstrap 4 with purpose theme.
Any help appreciated.

```
<div class="col-4">

                <!-- slider START -->

    <div class="input-slider-container mb-5">
        <div id="input-slider-red" class="input-slider input-slider--blue" data-range-value-min="10" data-range-value-max="100"></div>
        <span id="input-slider-red-value" class="range-slider-value" data-range-value-low="25"></span><span>&nbsp;miles</span>
    </div>     

                <!--slider END -->
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMqmf.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the utilities classes provided by bootstrap or your own form of css.

```
<div class="input-slider-container mb-5 d-flex">
        <div id="input-slider-red" class="input-slider input-slider--blue" data-range-value-min="10" data-range-value-max="100"></div>
        <span id="input-slider-red-value" class="range-slider-value" data-range-value-low="25"></span><span>&nbsp;miles</span>
    </div>
```

Try adding `d-flex` to your `input-slider-container` div.

Comment: Thanks, I used d-flex flex-row.
The value is to the right of the slider but the slider line has disappeared.
[link](https://imgur.com/OipzsbW)

Comment: try adding `flex-fill` to the div `class="input-slider input-slider--blue"`

Comment: `class="input-slider input-slider--blue flex-fill"`
no joy :(
results are the same.

Comment: @Joshhall, try moving `col-4` to the `input-slider-container` div. I see you are using that in your original post, also the `input-slider-container` is not provided by "bootstrap-4" are you using that from a different styles sheet?

Comment: here is a working example although note that the style class is 'custom-range' for bootstrap. [Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cdz7o0k8/29/)

Comment: I'm using a bootstrap theme called "purpose" maybe they have added additional classes.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still can't get it to work with your example.
This is all my code for the slider -
[link](https://pastebin.com/v34Ewyxq)

Comment: @JoshHall, the themes are created by third party people from bootstrap, so yes you probably are using there custom classes. You just need to try targeting the 'input-slider` class to give it a width. also change from `div` to `input` element. Im sure you have conflicting classes which is probably why you are having an issue.

Comment: tried all last night - but I must be missing something. Really eluding me. lol

Comment: @Joshhall, yeah without having access to the theme I can't really do much for you. Your browser has a way for you to trace the styles being applied based on the element. The only other thing I can see is try removing `d-inline-flex` from the parent div that you provided in your link if it is still there.

Comment: `<div class="bd-highlight" style="width: 400px">`
works but isn't responsive.